# Countif Multiple Criteria from within same column & Criteria from other columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to Count Multiple Criteria from one column in addition to a single piece of criteria from 2 other columns in one tab into a count on a separate tab of the same workbook in google sheets. I am using this to track progress in a project.

I have hacked together a formula that isn't working correctly:

`=((COUNTIFS(CCSS,"Number & Operations in Base Ten",Grade,{"K","1","2"},GoalStatus,{"Assigned to Writer","Goal Ready for Quality Review","Goal Quality Review Complete","Goal Ready for Copy Edit","Copy Edit Complete"})))`

I was trying to have the following happen:
COUNTIF Criteria CCSS (Column AD) is "Number & Operations in Base Ten"
**AND**
Grade Criteria (Column E) is K, 1, *OR* 2
**AND**
any of the following criteria are found in the GOALStatus Criteria (column B) {"Assigned to Writer","Goal Ready for Quality Review","Goal Quality Review Complete","Goal Ready for Copy Edit","Copy Edit Complete"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to approach it this way:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(CCSS, CCSS="Number & Operations in Base Ten", REGEXMATCH(Grade&"","K|1|2"), REGEXMATCH(GoalStatus,"Assigned to Writer|Goal Ready for Quality Review|Goal Quality Review Complete|Goal Ready for Copy Edit|Copy Edit Complete")))`

Here, we `FILTER` in only the results we want and then `COUNTA` them. The pipe symbol (`|`) in each `REGEXMATCH` means `OR`.

Comment: Wow, thanks Erik that totally solved my problem!!

Comment: Glad to know it worked. In case you are wondering, by the way, I appended &"" to Grade in that REGEXMATCH because it appears some of your Grade entries may have been pure numbers (e.g., 1, 2), and REGEX-type functions only work on strings. Appending a null character is a way to be sure that all entries will be seen as strings instead of numbers.